# Rearrange solution of differential equation involving SHM

Tags: calculus

This question involves simple harmonic motion (SHM).

I am struggling to work out how to rearrange:

$x(t)=A\cos(\omega t)+B\sin(\omega t)$

(Which is the solution of the differential equation involving the equation of motion)

into

$x(t) = a\sin(\omega t + \phi)$

So far I have got:

$x(t)=A\cos(\omega t)+B\sin(\omega t)= A\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\omega t)+B\sin(\omega t)$

But I really don't know what to do now to get it into the required form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using simple trigonometric identity, you have:

$$
a\sin (\omega t + \phi) = a\sin \omega t \cos \phi + a\cos \omega t \sin \phi
$$
Then equate like terms to get:
$$
A = a\sin \phi
$$
$$
B = a \cos \phi
$$

Then solve for $a$ and $\phi$ in terms of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score -1):

Multiply and divide by $\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$ and put $\sin \phi =\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} $

$$x(t)=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\left(\sin \phi\cos{\omega t}+\cos \phi \sin{\omega t}\right)$$

$$x(t)=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\left( \sin{(\omega t+\phi)}\right)$$